# Ping command windows 7

Tags: cmd, windows-7, ping

Hi i'm look for why my ping command doesn't work when it had a dash in the name for example

Ping HIL-BO

Will get:

Ping request could not find host HIL-BO. Please check the name and try again.

But when i type

Net view

[backslash][backslash] HIL-BO is in the outputted text

why wont this work please help

[/Screenshot/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3SMZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not ping to a windows network name except it the same as the DNS entry for your computers IP-address. I'm not a windows user, but the following should work. Try

```
ipconfig /a
```

This should show you a list that contains your IP-address. I expect that, you have no DNS entry so you must use the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx IP-address that will be shown by ipconfig.

```
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

(replace the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx by the displayed address). If you ping the same machine try:

```
ping localhost
```

The ping command can only work if the ping service on the target machine is running and the firewall is opend for ICMPv4 protocol and ports.