# Ping failure on windows 10

Tags: networking

I have a windows 10 machine and I am using proxy.I have internet access but whenever I try to ping any website on internet even google it says

```
"ping request could not find host www.google.com.Please check the name and try again".
```

I can only ping localhost

Comment: I found this duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34473769/ping-command-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at your DNS configuration?

On Windows, try

ipconfig /all